# gethostbyname( ) failed in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I use gethostbyname() to get the device IP. In iOS5, it works well. But in iOS6, the host value returned by gethostbyname() is NULL. Below is my code to get the current local IP of the device.

```
// retun the host name
- (NSString *)hostname
{
    char baseHostName[256];
    int success = gethostname(baseHostName, 255);
    if (success != 0) return nil;
    baseHostName[255] = '\0';

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s.local", baseHostName];
#else
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", baseHostName];
#endif
}

// return IP Address
- (NSString *)localIPAddress
{
    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname([[self hostname] UTF8String]);
    if (!host) {
        herror("resolv");
        return nil;
    }
    struct in_addr **list = (struct in_addr **)host->h_addr_list;
    return [NSString stringWithCString:inet_ntoa(*list[0]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Notice that, simulator works for both iOS5 and iOS6. Only iOS6 device failed.
What's the difference for the gethostbyname()?
Or do you have any other solution to get local ip in iOS6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several *possible* problems:

- Perhaps you have an IPv6 address (`gethostbyname()` works only with IPv4),
- or the name resolution from the hostname to IP address does not work correctly.

The following code returns all local addresses as an array of strings. It does not depend on name resolution and works with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netdb.h>

// return all local IP addresses
- (NSArray *)localIPAddresses
{
    NSMutableArray *ipAddresses = [NSMutableArray array] ;

    struct ifaddrs *allInterfaces;

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    if (getifaddrs(&allInterfaces) == 0) {
        struct ifaddrs *interface;

        // For each interface ...
        for (interface = allInterfaces; interface != NULL; interface = interface->ifa_next) {
            unsigned int flags = interface->ifa_flags;
            struct sockaddr *addr = interface->ifa_addr;

            // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
            if ((flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING)) {
                if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET || addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {

                    // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
                    getnameinfo(addr, addr->sa_len, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

                    [ipAddresses addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:host]];
                }
            }
        }

        freeifaddrs(allInterfaces);
    }
    return ipAddresses;
}
```

Comment: when in wifi, this method returns both 3G address and wifi address. how to find out which one is currently used?