# Get iPhone's IP Address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ip

I'm trying to obtain the device's IP Address with no luck.
All the methods I could find on Google and SO doesn't work.

For example, most recent answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084031/975959

I'm getting compilation errors:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'getifaddrs'

and

> Use of undeclared identifier 'freeifaddrs'

The I'm having the same problem as the one who asked this question. 
`gethostname()` return `*****s-iPhone` and using it in this line `struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(...)` returns `NULL`

I'm working on the device, but I guess compilation errors has nothing to do with it.

Any thoughts?

### P.S.

If it matters, I'm using Base SDK 6.0, deployment target 5.0

Comment: Well, I have written that answer, and I have verified that that code compiles with SDK 6.0, deployment target 5.0.

Comment: The IP address of the phone is going to be pretty remarkably useless.  If on a cell network, the IP address isn't route-able.  If on WiFi, it is almost assuredly going to be a NAT'd 192.168.*.* or a 10.*.*.* address, both of which won't be route-able from the generic Internet, either.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MartinR, It now works. Don't know why. I tried it many times since yesterday, and all of a sudden it works. Thanks. bbum, Yeah, I know, Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include those

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

Comment: I've included these files.
What frameworks need to be included?

Comment: @Lablabla No frameworks, I saw that they are automatically linked.

Comment: I've included these files, and I'm still getting the compilation errors

Comment: @Lablabla Where did you include them, and what SDK version are you using?

Comment: :) I've included them in my viewControler.mm files

Comment: Weird, After pressing CMD+B several times, it now builds successfully. I'm guessing it was scared by you helping me out :) Thanks man

Comment: @Lablabla next time please google the names of these headers. "What frameworks etc." can be easily answered seen that these are headers from the standard C library.

Comment: @H2CO3, They were included. I've added this code yesterday already and it didn't work either. don't know what's different now, after a few attempts

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project's target
2. Select "Build Settings" section
3. Search for "Link with Standard Libraries"
4. Set it to YES