# Objective-C Bridging Header section not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app and I'm trying to use a module called **react-native-socketio**.

In order to proceed with the app, I will need to bridge the objective C header in Xcode but the related section is missing.

According to the tutorial
[image: According to the tutorial]

[image: Xcode]

I have also noticed that the section **Swift Compiler – Code Generation** is also missing from Xcode.

Why?

Comment: Try `Build Settings` in target `iCare`. You are in project's Build Settings, not target's Build Settings !

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I am no expert in native iOS programming but I believe the tutorial is trying to bridge a swift file 'socket.swift' to my project right?

Comment: @DungProton no luck

Comment: @J.Doe check this ... how to use swift into obj-c http://stackoverflow.com/a/26873548/4601170  .. obj-c bridging header is not available in obj-c project

Comment: Sorry but you find which in Build Settings, `Header Search Paths` ?

Comment: @DungProton I dont understand

Comment: You can refer this tutorial 
http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: The answers here did not solve it for me. However, this did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135059/objective-c-bridging-header-not-visible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have resolved this matter by first adding a new swift file to the project, then the respective section appeared.

As you can probably tell, I now have an empty Swift file just sitting inside my project folder and options to bridge my header file.

[image]

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have created an `ObjectiveC` project instead of `Swift` (I can see the `AppDelegate.h` & `AppDelegate.m`). ObjC project wont have `Swift Compiler` section. Select `Swift` as language while creating project

Comment: I am working on a React Native project, it automatically create the entire Xcode file for me, which is in Objective C.

Comment: there should be way to choose the language. If you try to create a new project in Xcode you can choose Swift/ObjectiveC

Comment: There's no problem mixing ObjC and swift in the same app.

Comment: Yes you can use ObjC files in Swift project. can you do vice versa? @JeanRegisser

Comment: @JeanRegisser Thanks, I wasnt aware about that. I always choose language as `Swift` and add ObjC files, never tried vice versa. looks like when we add the first swift file to the project will get swift related settings and there is no difference if you choose swift/ObjC while creating the project :)