# Objective-C Bridging Header not visible

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode8, bridging-header

I am using Xcode 8.0, I have created Swift Bridging Header Manually. But I could not find the option `Ojective-C Bridging Header`  under `Swift Compiler – Code Generation`. (under Targets).
Please see the screenshot. Anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Build Setting` Section select the `All` tab instead of `Basic` and `Customized` then search for `Bridging Header` you will find it inside the `Swift Comipler - General` section. Same like below image.

[image]