# React native socket not getting initialized in release build (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, react-native

I am new to react-native and working on a project in react-native. I integrated socket using following code.

```
 this.socket = socketIO.connect(global.socketUrl, {
            jsonp: false,
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
            reconnectionAttempts: Infinity
        });
```

Further I created instance of SocketManager class in my component using below code.

```
Obj= new SocketManger()
```

This code is working fine in debug build, but we are getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined\n at new Socket
```

TIA

We also followed answer mention at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071929/objective-c-bridging-header-section-not-found)  but not getting any accurate result. with this code we are getting below error. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research i found my mistake. `global` variables doesn't work in IOS (`Release Build`). The issue was because of this global variable. 
So i changed my code to

```
this.socket = socketIO.connect('url', {
            jsonp: false,
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
            reconnectionAttempts: Infinity
        });
```

Now its working perfectly both in `Android` as well as `IOS`