# pod file #import statement gives file not found(iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have made a pod in which library code is written. When I installed pod to another project and then I imported, the class file not found error appeared. How to fix this issue? What is the exact problem?

Comment: make sure your classes header files are public that you want to make available.

Comment: When I install pod install in projects

Comment: OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DemoStaticLibrary/Pods-DemoStaticLibrary.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Comment: This warning comes, after installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there could be multiple cases for your problem. So, I would like to highlight some of the most common cases involved.

Things to note when installing a pod in Xcode project.

**1. Check target membership!**

Often the module or pod membership is not available to the workspace.

**2. Open Workspace, not Xcode Project.**

Often what beginners do after installing a pod is that they open the Xcode project. But!, you need to open xcode workspace after installing the pod.

**3. Install bridging Header.**

If your project uses Swift and pod includes Objective-C codes, you'll need to install a bridging header file and import the header files in there.

Bridging Header: [Link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header)

Comment: Open Workspace, not Xcode Project, Thanks Ariel. What a mess; but can be made to work.