# It gives errors when using Swift Static library with Objective-C project

Tags: ios, swift, static-libraries, swift4, xcode9.3

I need to make swift static library for my requirement. I made swift static library which uses swift and Obj-c code. I have included Obj-c files via bridge file. I am able to compile swift static library without any error and get libMySwift.a file. I use Xcode9.3 with Swift4 to compile library.

I include libMySwift.a in obj-c project and also included obj-c compatible header to access my lib in the project. When I try to compile the project it give below warning and more than 200 errors.

```
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftSwiftOnoneSupport
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftCore
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftQuartzCore
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftCoreImage
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftCoreGraphics
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftObjectiveC
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftDispatch
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftMetal
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftFoundation
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftUIKit
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftDarwin
Auto-Linking library not found for -lswiftCoreFoundation
```

Please let me know if I am missing any steps or need to add anything.

Comment: This can resolve your problem, It describes how to fix in details https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586937/1627358

Comment: @HussamKurd: There's another answer there (with a lot more upvotes) that worked for me.

Answer (score 69):

An update to Alex's answer:

In my case it was a React-Native project after adding a Swift Pods library. Maybe just the step 2 can work:

1. Adding a new Swift file and a Brigde header:

1) `File -> New -> File`
[image: <code>File -> New -> File</code>]

2) Select `Swift File` [image: Select <code>Swift File</code>]

3) Confirm `Create Bridging Header` [image]

2. Go to `Build Settings` and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` [image: Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries]

Comment: but the issue still present if you remove that swift file later :/

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my issue. By the way, I'm trying to build using react-native.

Comment: I've been spending two days trying to fix this issue and you saved me!

Comment: why i cant see Confirm Create Bridging Header dialog?

Comment: @TuanNguyen just create an empty header file by yourself. In the same directory and targets as your empty swift file. It worked for me.

Comment: I had to perform this again when upgrading from xcode 11 to 12.

Comment: if a bridging header dialog doesn't prompt, follow this. (to remove old one) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header

Comment: For me, with an ejected Expo/react-native project, I simply added the empty swift file and it worked. No bridge dialog needed. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 68):

I've got the same error on my demo project when added first Swift file in my pod compiled as static library. For me solution was simple - just added empty Swift file to my demo project which was previously in Objective-C only. This solved all linker errors.

Comment: by creating Objective-C bridging Header is resolved the issue.

Comment: Sweet. Kind of elegant solution. Xcode shows as warnings not errors. This solution fixed warnings and all erros caused by warnings.

Comment: I did this and still get the same error. Trying to ad adMob. Could not find auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101587/603082) worked for me: Add `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)` to the library search paths.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project name and select new file
2. Create an empty "Swift File" called File.Swift
3. It will prompt to create a bridge header file then click create

Answer (score 0):

If create empty "Swift File" errors

This method may be useful, can try ： https://blog.cpming.top/p/react-native-0-62-undefined-symbol

Answer (score 0):

I just follow AlVelig steps and still can't build the app, after making some hours on it finally works for me:
in Build, Setting -> Build Active Architecture Only -> Select yes for Release too (it was No)

Build Active Architecture Only:

[image]