# How to remove use_frameworks! AND keep using swift pods on an objective-c project?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

our project is an **Objective-c** project.

Since we're using `react-native-firebase` we [**can't use**](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1106#issuecomment-405030305) `use_frameworks!` in cocoapods any more.

The problem is we have a **swift pod dependency** ([PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)) and to use swift dependencies we must use `use_frameworks!` as far as I understand.

What I'm trying to do is have the best of both worlds, aka:

- remove `use_frameworks!` so that `react-native-firebase` works AND
- keep the `PromiseKit` swift dependency.

**current Podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'TestApp' do

    use_frameworks!

    # swift pod
    pod 'PromiseKit'

    # react-native-firebase
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'

end
```

I noticed there's this command `:modular_headers => true` or `use_modular_headers` which I sense may or may not be relevant to the solution I'm looking for since [Cocoapods 1.5](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/) but I can't seem to connect the dots.

## Edit:

If I remove `use_frameworks!` (even if I replace it with `use_modular_headers!`) I get this error:

[image]
Any help please?

Comment: I'm having the same issue react-native-firebase, and according to firebase documentation This is a restriction of Cocoapods and how it interacts with Dynamic Frameworks such as Firebase. 2) Don't have the use_frameworks! flag enabled,  but we need to  use react-native-augment library and  that explicitly requires  use_frameworks!  and it's base on swift, so If enable react-native-augment  works but react-native-firebase (FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found) does not and vice verse, :(

Answer (score 13):

Replace `use_frameworks!` with `use_modular_headers!` in the Podfile.

From the [CocoaPods 1.5 release note](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/) referenced:

> With CocoaPods 1.5.0, developers are no longer restricted into
>   specifying use_frameworks! in their Podfile in order to install pods
>   that use Swift. Interop with Objective-C should just work. However, if
>   your Swift pod depends on an Objective-C, pod you will need to enable
>   "modular headers" (see below) for that Objective-C pod.

With CocoaPods 1.9.0, it is now possible to build frameworks both statically and dynamically. Use `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Comment: I already tried that and it didn&#39;t work, I still get build errors with swift basic libraries missing.

Also I don't think promise kit depends on an objective c pod

Comment: Perhaps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096025/it-gives-errors-when-using-swift-static-library-with-objective-c-project/50495316#50495316

Comment: I'll try that and post back

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, here's the error https://d2ddoduugvun08.cloudfront.net/items/291W1l1f2D133t3P2f1S/Image%202018-10-23%20at%201.51.31%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=03b13312cd72b3bc9fa013eaf62629a5&v=08ca6eeb

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's still not finding the standard Swift libraries

Comment: Yeah, it says not found for `arm64` but I can't figure out why that is. Do I somehow have to specify the architecture manually to force it to build for arm64?

Comment: After six hours of extreme frustration, this is what solved it for me.

Comment: Can not use `use_modular_headers!`  on react-native project :( It conflict with react-native, I'm still finding a workable workaround :|

Comment: With CocoaPods 1.9.0, another option is `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Answer (score 9):

I have also faced this issue. and find a perfect solution for this.

https://github.com/joncardasis/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types

this is a plugin for cocoapods by which we can specify to use "dynamic framework" (i.e. what "use_framework" does) on a particular pod. this feature is not currently supported in cocoapods, that is why use this plugin to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I tried every solution, this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue last week, so I created a basic project where I'm using Swift, Firebase but *not* `use_frameworks!`, instead using bridging headers.

Don't know if people are still having issues with this, let me know if it helps. https://github.com/jenshandersson/React-Native-Swift