# xCode Cocoapods build fails "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I want to build my Xcode project (react native & swift) for the simulator and on a real device.

The simulator worked great. Today I tried to build it for my device, I selected my device in the Xcode bar and added the scheme to release (I had to do this because I'm using react native and otherwise the bundle is not packed)

Then an error during the build occurs (in this case for the dependency RNPurchases, but this is completely random. sometimes it's Expo-Keep-Awake or Facebook)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCPurchases", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in RNPurchases.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Even switching the back to Build Configuration `Debug` in my scheme has no effect anymore.

I already tried several things:

- clear Xcode build
- delete pod folder
- remove pod cache
- remove Xcode/DerivedData
- reboot

nothing works.

This problem is pretty new to me, it already occurred twice within the last 2 months. Somehow I got the build for the simulator running again, but never for a device. I didn't have the problems like this half a year ago ...

My Setup

- Xcode 12.4
- MacBook Pro (Big Sur 11.2.3)
- Build Settings for App-Target: Build Active Architectures Only: Debug YES, Release NO)
- Build Settings for Pod-Target: Build Active Architectures Only: Debug YES, Release NO)
- Podfile:

```
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
    require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb' # expo uni modules

    use_frameworks!

    install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false, :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false


    target 'TrainUrTeam' do
      platform :ios, '12.0'

      # ... pods xyz

      use_unimodules!

      config = use_native_modules!
      use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

    end


    post_install do |installer| # src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139830/6003494
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After 2 weeks of googling I could finally find a working solution according to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52911280/6003494) adding this to the `Podfile`:

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

Answer (score 2):

If `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` is not an option for you, you may try to use:

```
pre_install do |installer|
 installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
   if pod.name.eql?('RNPurchases')
     def pod.build_type;
     Pod::BuildType.static_library # pods version >= 1.9
     # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library #  pods version < 1.9
    end
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I got these errors and just restarted my macbook, clean, then build and they disappeared. Magic.

Comment: I was skeptical, but it did help

Answer (score -1):

> Go to xcode project -> Build setting -> Architecture -> Excluded
> architecture -> (arm64)set

Try to build & run

Comment: yes sure, but it did not work ... the error message says 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64' why should arm64 work?

Comment: @MarcoWeber it says "EXCLUDED" arch. I guess both arch are build and compilator doesn't take the good one. By excluding one you make sure it takes the x86_64 and not du arm64