# unable to run audioplayers flutter AndroidStudio

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I'm trying to play a song when a flat button is clicked. I imported the audioplayers package but I got an error when building the app. It's very long and I think it cames from an iOS relative problem but I don't know which. Here's the main parts of the error:

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           32,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility51'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMediaPlayer'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
```

At the end it looks like this:

```
 ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'audioplayers' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

If you have any suggestion please tell me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096025/it-gives-errors-when-using-swift-static-library-with-objective-c-project/50495316#50495316