# Swift dependency error analysis error not working even after changing swift language from 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, image, dependencies, alamofire

I have been facing swift dependency issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eda2J.png)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589018/the-swift-language-version-swift-version-build-setting-must-be-set-to-a-supp

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you check if the pods your are using are updated...

Comment: I am using Pod version 1.5.2 @cedricbahirwe