# How do I create an Objective-C bridging header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm following [this guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#section-add-app-groups-optional-but-recommended-) on adding OneSignal to React Native, and there is one section where is says:

`Open NotificationService.m or NotificationService.swift and replace the whole file contents with the code below:`

`<provides code to add>`

`If you are using Swift, make sure to create a separate Objective-C Bridging Header for your OneSignalNotificationExtensionService and add the following import:`

`#import "RCTOneSignalExtensionService.h"
Then you need to tell your Xcode project settings what your bridging header is named, like this.`

I added the code they provided to `NotificationService.swift` because that's the only one of the two files that exists in my project. So I assume I'm "using swift" as they put it. The problem is that when they say to `create a separate Objective-C Bridging Header`, I don't know how to do that. All I've been able to find online is that when you import Objective-C code into your swift project, Xcode should automatically prompt you to create a bridging header. Xcode hasn't done that for me.

Does anyone know how I can create an Objective-C bridging header?

Comment: Within Xcode you can use File > New, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new objective c class:

[image: You select New File]

then

[image: select cocoa touch class]

then you name it and specify as objective-c class at language

[image: select objective-c as language]

then you select your directory and hit create. At this point xcode is going to ask you whether or not you want to create bridging header. Yep do it.

[image]

And at the end it should look more or less like this at your project.

[image: Job done]

hope that helps you.

Comment: It just says to create a bridging header. Are you sure that I have to create a whole Objective-C class instead of just creating the header file?

Comment: Well you can do it by just adding a bridge header manually but you will have set building settings to that bridge header. Or you can just add a class and xcode will do that for you. Up to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header

Comment: briding header sometimes isn't created with these actions so answer is useless

Comment: This answer relies on tricking Xcode into noticing that you need the header. Sometimes work, sometimes doesn't. In Xcode 12, for instance, this never works.