# macOS Catalyst: How to read a USB device with Media Transfer Protocol? Is it possible with IOUSBHost API?

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst, mtp

I want to make a macOS app (Catalyst) interact with Nintendo Switch by USB cable. I found that Nintendo Switch will use MTP when launch “Copy to a Computer via USB Connection” function inside system settings.

Besides, I found an API, `IOUSBHost`, in Apple’s developer document. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iousbhost)

So my question is, is this API possible used with USB MTP devices? If not, can I found any alternative ways to achive that read USB MTP devices with macOS Catalyst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting interaction you need is copy files to and from Nintendo Switch, I would say you don't really need to create a driver to do the thing, and IOUSBHost is far too deep for your purposes.

There are already some implementations for MTP on macOS which I would start with.

Try libmtp: via [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libmtp), with their [sourceforge](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net) or forks on [github](https://github.com/indraniel/libmtp-macos).

libmtp is written in C, you will need to create a wrappers or use a bridging header if you want to use them in Swift to develop some complex application.

There are also some [helpers](https://github.com/ricohr/osx-mtphelper) for macOS that could work for you or could not.

Anyway, if the files-oriented interaction is what you want, focus on MTP libraries to implement things you need, not USB stuff.

Comment: I have no idea that can I use C library in Catalyst, for I just want to code my app with Catalyst because I already have an iPhone app and use Catalyst may help me complete CloudKit and make that programming progress easier. Anyway thanks for your advice, I will check it out.

Comment: You can use C libraries almost everywhere. To connect C library to the Swift project, you will need two steps: add it to link (e.g. enter path to .a file into other linker flags) and add its header to the Bridging Header ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231467/how-do-i-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header )