# Find IP address from device MAC address in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, arp

I am developing an iOS application which require ip address of device for communication, I have MAC address of  device from which I need to find IP address, there is available help for finding MAC address from IP address but not the same.

I have referred [LAN-Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) library but it is pinging each devices in network and and will get list of connected devices and for each ip address I need to find MAC address and compare with available MAC address.

My question is, Is there any way that we can find directly find ip address for particular MAC address in the network using Objective C?.

Comment: I can only imagine one "direct" way to get the IP address by a MAC address, exactly as you described: by going through all devices one by one.

Comment: check this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-ip-address/30754194#30754194

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone

Comment: @A-Live it is quite a lengthy process so finding some shortcut btw thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

This script should give you what you are looking for really quickly and requires to have nmap installed. The advantage is that if your host does not reply to ping probes, nmap would still find the host while other tools will not.

more info https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/how-do-i-know-the-ip-addresses-of-other-computers-in-my-network