# How to get device's IP address if use NEHotspotConfigurationManager?

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension

I use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754194/7144402) to get device's IP address, and it works fine if device already connect to specific Wi-Fi, but if I use `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` to force divice connect to Wi-Fi, it returns something strange, what's the problem?

Here's my code:

```
let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: "SSID", passphrase: "password", isWEP: false)
configuration.joinOnce = true

NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        if error?.localizedDescription == "already associated." {
            ip = self.getIPAddresses() // return 192.168.x.x
        } else {
            // no connected
        }
    } else {
        // connected
        ip = self.getIPAddresses() // return fe80::6034:fb02:100:0%pdp_ip0
    }
```

**NOTE:** `getIPAddresses()` is just the same with the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754194/7144402)

Comment: please post the getIPAddresses function along with the question

Comment: @ShamsudheenTK It's in the link, the only different is function name. i.e. I am using Swift 3 version.