# Swift - Get ipv6 link local address?

Tags: ios, swift, ipv6

I checked the below code to get ipv6 address and this code returned global unicast address like '2001:x:x...'.
But I want to get link local address like 'fe80:...'.
How can I get link local address by using the below code?

```
static var ipAddress: String? {
    var ipv6 : String?
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return (nil, nil) }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return (nil, nil) }

    for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let interface = ifptr.pointee
        let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
        if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
            if  name == "en0" {
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),&hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                ipv6 = String(cString: hostname)
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    return ipv6
}
```

Comment: That code [looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754194/1187415)  :)

Comment: @MartinR, Yes I referred the above link :) But, I dont know how to get link local address even after googling several websites.

Comment: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if there are still problems.

Answer (score 3):

The system include file `netinet6/in6.h` defines a macro

```
#define IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(a)        \
        (((a)->s6_addr[0] == 0xfe) && (((a)->s6_addr[1] & 0xc0) == 0x80))
```

That macro is not imported into Swift, but shows how we have to proceed.
The following modification of the loop (from [Swift - Get device's WIFI IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-ip-address/30754194#30754194)) finds all IPv6 link-local addresses:

```
for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
    let interface = ifptr.pointee
    let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
    if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {
        // Get the sin6_addr part of the sockaddr as UInt8 "array":
        let s6_addr = interface.ifa_addr.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr_in6.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0.pointee.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr8
        }
        // Check for link-local address:
        if s6_addr.0 == 0xfe && (s6_addr.1 & 0xc0) == 0x80 {
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```