# Swift Get IP address of current device in wifi and cellular

Tags: swift, xcode, ip-address, swift5

```
   func getIPAddress() -> String {
    var address: String?
    var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
    if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
        var ptr = ifaddr
        while ptr != nil {
            defer { ptr = ptr?.pointee.ifa_next }

            let interface = ptr?.pointee
            let addrFamily = interface?.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
            if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                // wifi = ["en0"]
                // wired = ["en2", "en3", "en4"]
                // cellular = ["pdp_ip0","pdp_ip1","pdp_ip2","pdp_ip3"]

                let name: String = String(cString: (interface!.ifa_name))
                if  name == "en0" || name == "en2" || name == "en3" || name == "en4" || name == "pdp_ip0" || name == "pdp_ip1" || name == "pdp_ip2" || name == "pdp_ip3" {
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    getnameinfo(interface?.ifa_addr, socklen_t((interface?.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len)!), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                    address = String(cString: hostname)
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    }
    return address ?? ""
}
```

I have use this one and run the program in iOS simulator its giving nil value. I have added the Bridging-Header file and  #include in it.

for retrieve the value I have used

```
let stringIPAddress : String = self.getIPAddress()
```

can I know is that possible to get IP address with simulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Get device's WIFI IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-wifi-ip-address)

Comment: Yes. But getting nil in the response

Comment: @Gereon I have used the above code, but I get nil value when I run in simulator

Answer (score 6):

**Code works for Swift 5+ and iOS 13+**

To get **IPAddress** of device on turning **Wifi** or **Wired** or **Mobile data** ON, use below method :

```
func getIPAddress() -> String? {
    var address : String?

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

    // For each interface ...
    for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let interface = ifptr.pointee

        // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
        let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
        if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

            // Check interface name:
            // wifi = ["en0"]
            // wired = ["en2", "en3", "en4"]
            // cellular = ["pdp_ip0","pdp_ip1","pdp_ip2","pdp_ip3"]
            
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
            if  name == "en0" || name == "en2" || name == "en3" || name == "en4" || name == "pdp_ip0" || name == "pdp_ip1" || name == "pdp_ip2" || name == "pdp_ip3" {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                            &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                address = String(cString: hostname)
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

    return address
}
```

Here, code/checks works for **Wifi**, **Wired** and **Mobile data** is:

> if name == "en0" || name == "en2" || name == "en3" || name == "en4" || name == "pdp_ip0" || name == "pdp_ip1" || name == "pdp_ip2" || name == "pdp_ip3"

Hope will be helping! :)

Comment: how do I get it in the format of xxx.xx.xx.xx ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this code, which has worked in simulator as well as playgrounds:

```
public class EnumerateNetworkInterfaces {
    public struct NetworkInterfaceInfo {
        let name: String
        let ip: String
        let netmask: String
    }
    public static func enumerate() -> [NetworkInterfaceInfo] {
        var interfaces = [NetworkInterfaceInfo]()

        // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
        if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {

            // For each interface ...
            var ptr = ifaddr
            while( ptr != nil) {

                let flags = Int32(ptr!.pointee.ifa_flags)
                var addr = ptr!.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee

                // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
                if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {
                    if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                        var mask = ptr!.pointee.ifa_netmask.pointee

                        // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                        let zero  = CChar(0)
                        var hostname = [CChar](repeating: zero, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                        var netmask =  [CChar](repeating: zero, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                        if (getnameinfo(&addr, socklen_t(addr.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                        nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                            let address = String(cString: hostname)
                            let name = ptr!.pointee.ifa_name!
                            let ifname = String(cString: name)


                            if (getnameinfo(&mask, socklen_t(mask.sa_len), &netmask, socklen_t(netmask.count),
                                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                                let netmaskIP = String(cString: netmask)

                                let info = NetworkInterfaceInfo(name: ifname,
                                                                ip: address,
                                                                netmask: netmaskIP)
                                interfaces.append(info)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ptr = ptr!.pointee.ifa_next
            }
            freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        }
        return interfaces
    }
}
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
for interface in EnumerateNetworkInterfaces.enumerate() {
    print("\(interface.name):  \(interface.ip)")
}
```