# iOS app hosting HTTP Server - Making it public

Tags: ios, swift, http, networking, server

I would like my iOS app to host a small HTTP server, such that other app users can download files from the host.

I've tried using both [Telegraph](https://github.com/Building42/Telegraph) and [Swifter](https://github.com/httpswift/swifter). I can get the server to work on `localhost` but I can't figure out how to

1. Get the device's IP where the server is hosted
2. Configure it to host publicly at this IP

**Telegram Code**

```
let server = Server()
try! server.start(port: 9000)
    
let demoBundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Demo", withExtension: nil)!
server.serveDirectory(demoBundleURL, "/demo")
    
server.route(.GET, "status") { (.ok, "Server is running") }
```

**SWIFTER CODE**

```
let server = HttpServer()
server["/"] = scopes {
  html {
    body {
      center {
        img { src = "https://swift.org/assets/images/swift.svg" }
      }
    }
  }
}
server["/files/:path"] = directoryBrowser("/")

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
do {
  try server.start(9080, forceIPv4: true)
  print("Server has started ( port = \(try server.port()) ). Try to connect now...")
  semaphore.wait()
} catch {
  print("Server start error: \(error)")
  semaphore.signal()
}
```

Comment: server is hosted local. you can access it at `localhost` ip address - `127.0. 0.1` .

Comment: I would like to make a public server that anyone on the web can access. Is this possible?

Comment: as long as your device has static ip it is possible but I am not sure carriers around the globe provide static IPs to mobile devices. you will need something in middle for latest ip.

Comment: I think it is better to find the ip device that is to be hosted first and then send it to others using BLE or nFc. The link below may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-wifi-ip-address

Comment: showmyip.com or similar services.